# In D6 Rules, how do I grab a string variable from an event?

Tags: 6, rules

I have a D6 Rules custom event(1), that captures a string argument when invoked(2). I also have a custom condition(3) that I want to work in conjunction with this event. I need the string argument *passed from the event* to show up in the condition, so that I can match it against another string(4).

With the code as I have it now, a field for argument shows up to be configured on the 'add condition' >> 'Foo response code equals value'  page (instead of being pulled from the event). This is because the [rules data type](http://drupal.org/node/298633) string uses an input form.

**My question: how can I access a string variable, passed by an event, in a condition?**

(1)

```
function foobar_rules_event_info() {
 $events = array(
    'group' => t('foo'),
  );
   return array(
    'foo_contactCreate' => $events + array(
      'label' => t('Sending new foo contactCreate'),
      'variables' => array(
        'foo_response' => array('type' => 'string', 'label' => t('created foo contact')),
      ),
    ),
```

(2) $foo_response is a string

```
// Invoke event wrappers
function rules_foo_contactCreate($foo_response) {
  rules_invoke_event('foo_contactInfo', $foo_response);
}
```

(3) foo_response should be the argument passed from the event

```
/*
 *  Implementation of hook_condition_info
 */

function foobar_rules_condition_info() {
    $items = array(
      'foobar_foo_response_condition' => array(
        'label' => t('FOO response code equals value'),
        'description' => t('Checks the response code from a FOO command. The condition returns TRUE, if the FOO response code has the given value'),
        'module' => 'foobar',
        'arguments' => array(
          'foo_response' => array(
            'type' =>  'string',
            'label' => t('Received FOO Response Code'),
            'value' => ''
          ),
        ),
    //   'foo_response_codes' => array(
    //     'type' => 'list<string>',
    //     'label' => t('Wanted FOO Response Code'),
    //   ),
      ),
    );
    return $items;
}
```

(4) Desired conditional is currently commented out in line 3

```
function foobar_response_condition($passed_response_code) {
  if ($passed_response_code) {
  // if ($passed_response_code == $wanted_response_code) {
    return TRUE;
  }
  else {
    return FALSE;
  }
}
```